# Bridging built in ethernet with USB ethernet adapter in debian

Tags: networking

I have Debian 10 (no X11 because it doesn't work) on an iMac that has built in ethernet that I can configure using `/etc/network/interfaces` and it works.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug enp2s0

auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.51
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

I want to bridge this with a USB ethernet adapter so that everything on each side can see everything on the other side, all with 192.168.1.0 addresses, as if everything was plugged into the same switch.

Having read https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections#Bridging_with_a_wireless_NIC I came up with

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug enp2s0

iface enp2s0 manual

iface enx00808e8c92f8 manual

iface br0 inet static
        bridge_ports enp2s0 enx00808e8c92f8
        address 192.168.1.51
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

but this ends up with no network at all.

```
root@imac51:/etc/network# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:cb:9c:eb:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enx00808e8c92f8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:80:8e:8c:92:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I don't understand.
That should work, right?
What have I got wrong?
Is it even possible to join two physical networks like this?

I heard that maybe this file is being ignored because of something called `systemd-networkd`. How can I tell if I've got that? Which is the correct way to do it? If not this file then does this mean that https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration is now completely wrong? Is there some correct documentation?

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I cannot understand what you need to achieve. I'll try to give you a hand in achieving it though :)

First of all, `systemd-networkd` is not used in Debian 10 Buster. At least not by default. The interfaces are still set up in `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Next, if network manager is installed, stop it before you proceed; it may try to setup interfaces by itself.
`sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager`

I suggest you to try to setup a bridge manually at first, using commands on shell. After you are happy with the result, move the configuration to `/etc/network/interfaces`. So,

(`sudo` in front of each command, or `sudo su` to switch to root shell)

Setup the bridge:

```
ip link add br0 type bridge
ip link set br0 up
```

Assign the 2 physical NICs to the bridge (they lose settings when assigned)

```
ip link set enp2s0 master br0
ip link set enx00808e8c92f8 master br0
```

Now the bridge can be treated as an ordinary NIC. To acquire an IP from DHCP:

```
dhclient -v br0
```

or static (assuming the gateway):

```
ip addr add 192.168.1.51/24 dev br0
ip route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
```

Perhaps going step by step will help you locate the problem.

Comment: I see all these commands for setting up the bridge; does this mean that bridges are set up with commands and not with the `interfaces` file? Do you have to put the commands somewhere so that the bridge doesn't get lost when the machine restarts?

Comment: Of course a bridge can be set up using `interfaces` file. I'm suggesting going step by step using commands to troubleshoot.

Comment: I think I see; it's very confusing having lots of different ways of doing the same thing and which seem to conflict with eachother. I'll give it a go...

Comment: Indeed. Have in mind that there were also `bridge-utils` in older Linux distros, `brctl` command, which you'll meet if searching the net. They are deprecated.

Comment: Well `br0` is now listed in `ip a` but I can't connect from a machine on one side to a machine on the other, or SSH into the machine with the bridge on the IP address assigned to the bridge...

Comment: ip route add fails: any valid prefix is expected rather than "default".

Answer (score 0):

I had not done

```
# apt-get install bridge-utils
# brctl addbr br0
```

Therefore there was no `br0` device for `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure.

I though that simply referring to `br0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` would create it, but not so: it must already exist in `ip a`; the `brctl` command above creates it.

Here is the full story: [http://igor.gold.ac.uk/~mas01rwb/pages/imac-ubuntu.html](http://igor.gold.ac.uk/%7Emas01rwb/pages/imac-ubuntu.html)